# Deletion of Google Backup and Sync Tool Folder

Tags: windows-10, backup, data-recovery, google-drive

I am using Google Backup and Sync Tool to backup files. What happens when I accidentally delete a folder from my laptop which is syncing to Google Drive with this Tool? It may delete my previous sync files from Google Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It may delete my previous sync files from Google Drive?
```

No way. This is the whole idea, to have a backup of your files somewhere.

Still, there are some settings in this regard. If you go to the settings of *Backup and Sync from Google* Static Software Application, you will see that it *is* possible to also set it to delete the cloud version when you have deleted the local version.

There is no way to tell it that you have just *accidentally* deleted your local folder. I think that on the first deletion, in the System Tray you get exactly this kind of question - whether you want it deleted also from the cloud. You can set it by answering to the question asked in the System Tray or even by going to the *Preferences* Pane of this Software Utility and examining there more options.